# Java : Is there a way to automatically cast a return value?

Tags: java, inheritance, types

I have two classes :

```
public abstract class Arguments {
    public List execute() {
        // do some stuff and return a list
    }
}

// and a child :
public class ItemArguments {
    public List<Item> execute() {
        return super.execute();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method execute in ItemArguments is a bit useless, but without it, I have to cast all my calls to the execute method in Arguments.

Is there a way to remove the execute method in ItemArguments and avoid having the cast to do where the calls are made ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generics

```
public abstract class Arguments<T> {
  public List<T> execute() {
    // some stuff
    return new ArrayList<T>();
  }
}

public class ItemArguments extends Arguments<Item> {

}
```

You don't even need to subclass unless you have other reasons to do so

```
public class Arguments<T> {
  public List<T> execute() {
    // blah
  }
}

Arguments<Item> o1 = new Arguments<Item>();
List<Item> o2 = o1.execute();
```

Calling methods on T is not quite so straightforward. T is erased by the compiler and so it's not available at runtime. An easy to understand workaround is to pass in the class when you instantiate Arguments

```
public class Foo {
  public static void something() { ... }
}

public class Arguments<T extends Foo> {
  private Class<? extends Foo> foo;
  public Arguments(Class<? extends Foo> foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  public List<T> execute() {
    foo.something();

  }
}
```

There are better ways, but this is mostly understandable without being a patterns master :)

Comment: Just a little question : How can I use T ? I need to call a static method located in T. I think a good way is to use Reflection, but T.getDeclaredMethod isnt working :/